# Form not submitting to server - knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a basic html form. I am using knockout.js to do some client/server side action. I am able to add or remove contacts as pleased. I am running into problems when submitting the values. When I click the submit button, the form is not being redirected anywhere. I believe it is due to the `self.save = function`. How can I properly submit the values of the whole form? [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dLbY7/18/)

```
var initialData = [{
    firstName: "Jenny",
    lastName: "LaRusso",
    phone: "(555) 121-2121",
    alt_phone: "(555) 123-4567",
    main1: false,
    main2: true    
}, {
    firstName: "Sensei",
    lastName: "Miyagi",
    phone: "(555) 444-2222",
    alt_phone: "(555) 999-1212",
    main1: true,
    main2: false
}];

var ContactsModel = function (contacts) {
    var self = this;
    self.contacts = ko.observableArray([]);

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(contacts, function (contact) {
        self.contacts.push({
            firstName: contact.firstName,
            lastName: contact.lastName,
            phone: contact.phone,
            alt_phone: contact.alt_phone,
            main1: ko.observable(contact.main1),
            main2: ko.observable(contact.main2)
        });
    });

    self.addContact = function () {
        self.contacts.push({
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            phone: "",
            alt_phone: "",
            main1: false,
            main2: false
        });
    };

    self.removeContact = function (contact) {
        self.contacts.remove(contact);
    };

    self.addPhone = function (contact) {
        contact.phones.push({
            number: ""
        });
    };

    self.removePhone = function (phone) {
        $.each(self.contacts(), function () {
            this.phones.remove(phone)
        })
    };

    self.save = function () {
            self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.contacts), null, 2));
        };


    self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("");

    //This is not working
    $.post("/some/url.php", initialData, function(returnedData) {
        // This callback is executed if the post was successful   
    })
};

ko.applyBindings(new ContactsModel(initialData));
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? just save the values? in that case you can just make an ajax call and send the lastSavedJson as a parameter to the save method back at server

Comment: @FlaviaObreja yes I would like to just save the values to the server on the button click. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very good tutotial is the one from knokcout website: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving. As described there, one way to do it is to have a form tag defined where you have a hidden field which contains the JSON representation of your contacts observableArray:

```
<form action="/contacts/saveform" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="contacts" data-bind="value: ko.toJSON(contacts)" />
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

When the visitor submits the form, your server-side code will receive that JSON data. The second method would be that you send your model data to the server using an Ajax request.

```
<button data-bind="click: save">Save</button>
```

and then implement the save function :

```
var ContactsModel = function (contacts) {
    self.save = function() {
        $.ajax("/contacts/saveform", {
            data: ko.toJSON({ contacts: self.contacts }),
            type: "post", contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(result) { alert(result) }
        });
    }; 
}
```

Comment: With method one, how can i store this in mysql db with php?

Comment: What do you recommend here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22136156/saving-values-into-a-json-object-when-keypress-checkbox-or-select-is-triggered?